# Manage JBPM workflow parametres

Tags: jbpm

How can parameters be passed from a workitem of a JBPM-workflow to a custom JAVA class? Is there any native function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass parameter between workitem and java class using a Script Task and the property Parameter Mapping that you can find in Properties TAB. 
Follow the guide:

https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMBPMN2.html#d0e2742